# How save changed in all buffers (Embark export: consult-grep)?

Tags: replace, consult

1. consult-grep
   #hello#
   [image]
2. embark-export

[image]

3. C-x C-q
4. replace-string
   hello -> hi
   [image]

As you can see it's change in buffer "Embark Export: consult-grep".

But how to save this changes in all files (test_2.txt, test-1.txt, test3.txt) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [wgrep](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-wgrep) for that. Install and load it, then in the 'Exported grep results' buffer press `C-c C-p` (`wgrep-change-to-wgrep-mode`),
replace the strings, and finish by pressing `C-x C-s` (`wgrep-finish-edit`).

Some more info you can find [here](https://github.com/oantolin/embark/issues/47).